# Angular Karma Coverage No specs found

Tags: angular, sonarqube, karma-jasmine

I'm using Angular 15.2.9,
Korma and Jasmin for testing

I'm integrating sonarQube, which works almost perfectly, I can't make the test coverage work. I know why, because when I throw `ng test --code-coverage`, it gives me errors and "No spec Founds" in Chromium.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdBqx.png)

Here is my karma.conf.js :

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-sonarqube-reporter'),
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
        // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
        // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
        // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    sonarqubeReporter: {
      basePath: 'src/app',
      filePattern: '**/*spec.ts',
      encoding: 'utf-8',
      outputFolder: 'reports',
      legacyMode: false,
      reportName: function (metadata) {
        return 'sonarqube_report.xml';
      },
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/taxppenc-front'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' },
        { type: 'lcov' }
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless', 'ChromeHeadlessCI'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

My angular.json :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "taxppenc-front": {
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "fr-CH"
      },
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "print-js",
              "lodash"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist/taxppenc-front",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/sass/themes/mytheme/theme.scss",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "baseHref": "/taxppenc-front/"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "2mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "10kb",
                  "maximumError": "200kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "mock": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/app/environments/environment.mock.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/app/environments/environment.development.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "test": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/app/environments/environment.test.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "xx:build:production"
            },
            "mock": {
              "browserTarget": "xx:build:mock"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "xx:build:development"
            },
            "test": {
              "browserTarget": "xx:build:test"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "taxppenc-front:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@angular-eslint/schematics"
    ],
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Here are the errors thrown :

```
⠙ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ep220027/projects/taxppenc-front/src/polyfills.ts'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:589:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:457:35)
    ./src/app/modules/contribuable/components/contribuable-informations/contribuable-informations.component.spec.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.

./src/app/modules/xx/components/xx/xx/xx.spec.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.
```

When y specify a karma key preprocessor and files, it fails as well, except for javascript files, but for typescripts ones, it fails. I tried karma-typescript, istanbul-coverage but it's still failing.

Any solutions ?

Thanks :)